# Django runtime error: conflicting models. Best approach to split models.py file into models subfolder

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have my django apps inside **apps** folder. Due to multiple **article** types I decided to split my models.py for the **articles** app and put it inside the **models** folder where each *modelname*.py file points to a model.

**Problem**: configuring syndication framework (as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/syndication/) causes a runtime error `Conflicting 'news' models in application 'articles': <class 'articles.models.news.News'> and <class 'apps.articles.models.news.News'>`.

**Note:** Before adding syndication framework functionality everything works just fine.
**I tried:** Adding `app_label` to the **News** model.

**`apps` folder structure:**

```
├── articles
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── feeds.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── articles.py
│   │   ├── categories.py
│   │   ├── news.py
│   │   ├── reviews.py
│   │   └── tags.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── news.py
├── conftest.py
├── education
├── __init__.py
├── users
```

**`/apps/articles/models/news.py`:**

```
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
    //
    // Model Fields
    //

    class Meta:
        ...
        app_label = 'articles'
        ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("articles:news_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

**`/apps/articles/feeds.py`:**

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .models.news import News


class NewsEntriesFeed(Feed):
    title = _("News")
    link = "/news/"
    description = _("Latest news")

    def items(self):
        return News.objects.order_by('-publish_date')[:5]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.lead
```

**`/apps/articles/urls.py`:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views.news import NewsDetailView, NewsListView
from .feeds import NewsEntriesFeed

app_name = "articles"

urlpatterns = [
    path("news/", NewsListView.as_view(), name="news_list"),
    path("news/<str:slug>/", NewsDetailView.as_view(), name="news_detail"),
    path("feed/rss", NewsEntriesFeed(), name="news_feed"),
]
```

**`/apps/articles/apps.py`**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ArticlesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'articles'
```

**INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   ...
   "apps.articles.apps.ArticlesConfig",
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelsoutsidemodels.html.
According to listing `7-42` (first approach) steps to split models into models directory are:

1. Create **models** directory inside the specific app folder, alongside **models.py** file which you want split
2. Create **`__init__.py`** inside **models** folder
3. Next, inside the **models** folder create multiple **.py** files with Django models declared as they would typically be done inside **models.py**. You can have as many models as needed in each `.py` file and as many **.py** files as you deem necessary (e.g. one model per file)
4. the **`__init__.py`** file must make a relative import for each of the models -inside **.py** files - to make them visible to the app
5. This one-line syntax - `from .<file> import <model_class>` - must be used in **`__init__.py`** for every model declared in **.py** files inside the models folder.

**Note:**  for more information and tips, see https://www.webforefront.com/django/modelsoutsidemodels.html